# PHPExcel авто ширина колонки

Tags: phpexcel, php

Как в PHPExcel задать авто ширинк колонки?

Comment: В *PHP* - не знаю.
Вдруг поможет: в *Excel* - *ColumnWidth*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Документацию пробовали открывать? В Word-варианте пункт 4.6.28 называется "**Setting a column’s width**".

> If you want PHPExcel to perform an
> automatic width calculation, use the
> following code. PHPExcel will
> approximate the column with to the
> width of the widest column value.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
```

Comment: да, спасибо, я уже нашел было :)

Comment: а если `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('')->setAutoSize(true);` то применится ко всем столбцам?